# Issue shell commands to a remote server via website?

Tags: shell, ssh, remote-server

In short, I'd like to issue a command in a directory on a remote server from my website! Maybe somebody can suggest an easy way to do this. At first I'd thought there'd be some Javascript ssh tunnel to use, but it seems that's too much of a security issue.

Basically my website contains a form that I'd like to use to generate a shell command. The shell command will be of the form:

```
python my_script.py -date xxx -risk 1
```

Where the arguments are generated from the form. The shell command must be executed in a specific path on a **remote machine**. This is the difficult part. It seems easy to execute commands on a local machine, but I have no idea how to do it from the web on a remote machine! The remote machine, in turn, generates several HTML, csv, and other files; and automatically pushes them to the website server via SSH.

Maybe I could issue a command to open and SSH tunnel on the web server to the remote machine, then issue the command? Is this possible?

**Note**
I know how to generate the commands from the HTML form. My concern is how to execute the command from a button click!

Comment: In php exec function come to run the command have you tried with that ?

Comment: Can I send Javascript variables (from the html form) to php?

Comment: Using ajax you can send variable in to php where you can use for php code

Comment: Can you provide an example and I'll mark you as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Check below code.

**Button**

```
  <button class="button">Click here</button>
```

**Ajax call**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').click(function(){

         var clickid= 'YOUR_DATA';

        $.ajax
       ({ 
            url: 'ajax.php',
            data: {"clickid": clickid},
            type: 'post',
            success: function(result)
            {
                alert('Successfully run!!!');
            }
        });
     });
});
 </script>
```

**Ajax.php file**

```
<?php 
  if(isset($_POST['clickid']))
  {
      $clickid= $_POST['clickid']; // get the data of ajax value.

      exec('python my_script.py -date xxx -risk 1'); // Your command
 }
?>
```

Comment: Ok, but the command needs to be executed on a different server other than the web server! How can this be done?